# skiimage.measure in python

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am using these line of the code below. It works for me and it gave me the data that I want. However, I do not understand what does region props(properties) use as units? Let say I am calculating diameter of a bubble, what will be the unit of my diameter (mm?), and how I can converted to obtained output value to one with physical meaning?
I am saying that, as I obtained a diameter equal to 16 and my domain data and domain image is only between 0 and 8, which does not make sense! unless it needs some correction factors!

Do you have please any explanations in this concern? I am new to skimage, so any detailed information will be helpful.

Thank you

```
from skimage import measure

labels = measure.label(Bubble, connectivity=None) 

props  = measure.regionprops_table(labels, properties=['label','area', 'equivalent_diameter', 'centroid'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The units are pixels. So if the pixel spacing is 3mm/pixel, then you must multiply by 3 to get the measurement in your preferred units. You can do this with, for example:

```py
props['equivalent_diameter_mm'] = props['equivalent_diameter'] * 3
props['area_mm2'] = props['area'] * 3**2  # assuming your images are 2D
```

Also note, thanks to [PR 6296](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/6296), the next version of scikit-image (either 0.20 or 1.0, we are having that discussion right now! ) will allow you to write:

```py
props = measure.regionprops_table(
        labels,
        properties=['label', 'area', 'equivalent_diameter'],
        spacing=[3, 3],  # one value per dimension
        )
```

and get the measurements in your units directly.

Comment: Thank you. I just posted a question regarding how pixel spacing should be determined.